# Can I broadcast in a network but exclude myself?

Tags: c#, broadcast, server

I'm using C# to create a client-server network. I created client successfully but i have an issue with the server. When i broadcast a message to the server it's supposed to send it to other clients as well. The problem is that the server too gets the message then it thinks it's another message and it creates an infinite loop that sends the same message over and over again. Can I broadcast excluding the server?

```
public void serverThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient_rec.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
        if (returnData.StartsWith("broad"))
        {
            UdpClient udpClient_send = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 8400);  
            //can i use something else here instead of broadcast to send it to everyone except myself(server)?
            udpClient_send.EnableBroadcast = true;
            udpClient_send.Send(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length, RemoteIpEndPoint1);
            udpClient_send.Close();
        }
        this.SetText(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ": " + returnData.ToString());
        this.SetText2(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, no. There's no way to say, "Broadcast to everybody but me." Perhaps you should change your message format so that it has a "from" field. That way, the server can ignore any messages that it sent to itself.

Comment: If the server has a special relationship -- i.e. to rebroadcast messages -- then why are you using broadcast to transmit data to it in the first place? There are lots of ways to work around the issue, but it seems to me that there's a fundamental problem with the design in the first place.

Comment: +1. Whoever designed that did it without - considering how networks work. Broken design.

Comment: Agreed, broadcast is exactly that, similar to a radio station broadcast, either the client has the radio on or off.